# Read a Drag and Dropped file

Tags: javascript, html

I tried uploading files with the dataTransfer.files but what is the method or property that should be used for reading a single file?

Answer (score 24):

**FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()**
Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains an ArrayBuffer representing the file's data.

**FileReader.readAsBinaryString()**
Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains the raw binary data from the file as a string.

**FileReader.readAsDataURL()**
Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains a data: URL representing the file's data.

**FileReader.readAsText()**
Starts reading the contents of the specified Blob, once finished, the result attribute contains the contents of the file as a text string.
following demo can be helpful for you 
**[Demo](http://html5demos.com/file-api)**

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.result);
    //holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center';

  };
  console.log(file);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```